# npm: "Error: invalid version: 1.0" while installing grunt plugins

Tags: gruntjs

While yesterday all works fine, today i am getting the printed error below, when i try to install a grunt plugin, wether it is a official grunt contrib or vendor plugin.
I am running grunt v0.4, node v0.8.20 and npm v1.2.11, System X 10.8.2.

```
npm install grunt-<plugin>-<name> --save-dev
npm ERR! Error: invalid version: 1.0
npm ERR!     at validVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:590:40)
npm ERR!     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:342:23)
...
```

What suprises me is that also official grunt contrib plugins (grunt-contrib-xxx) fails to install altough i expect it has a proper semver version syntax. npm-debug.log shows nothing additional to the verbose output in the console.

Any hints are appreciated.

Thx in advance
felic

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for replying this late.

I am new to the grunt/nodejs stuff, so I was a bit confused and it took a while to understand what's wrong: I updated `grunt` to 0.4.~ at that point without editing the related project package.json to reflect the correct grunt versioning ("1.0.0" instead of "0.1.0"). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, neither the grunt docs, nor the symver docs make this very clear, but dotted triple is required.  You can verify it like this: `node node_modules/semver/bin/semver 1.0.0 ; echo $?` which should return the version, followed by exit-status-code 0 for success.  An invalid version will return status code 1 for failure.

Comment: You shouldn't have to edit the `package.json` file manually. Run `$ npm install grunt --save-dev` and `grunt` will update to the latest version, also writing the dependency's updated version to the `package.json` file automatically (because of the `--save-dev` part). That is the same for any other dependency or `grunt` plugin.

Comment: I ran into this problem when I changed my app version from our pre-release of 0.9.4 to 1.0.0.0  Turns out npm doesn't like 4 digits version numbers. Once I changed this to 1.0.0, everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Modify package.json to

```
"devDependencies" : {
   "grunt" : "latest" 
}
```

Now run

```
sudo npm install
```

This installs latest grunt.

[Note : Add required dependencies to object and the command will install it all on run]

Answer (score -1):

since grunt 0.4 is aimed at the v1 of node maybe the plugin you're trying to install asks for a 1.0 version of node, try to read the package.js of the plugins yo're trying to install. 
as glortho asked, you could tell us explicitely what plugin causes the problem

Comment: v1 of node? wat? it's 2014 and node is still on 0.10